# I'm making an NLP app but models are too big

Tags: java, android, nlp, apk, opennlp

I'm making an Android app that does some Natural Language Processing. The app itself works fine except the models OpenNLP give are big so the apk is too large for distribution. What should I do to make the apk smaller? I was thinking about using a server to do the NLP but I have no clue how to go about it

Comment: Lol this is just to test NLP. I don't plan to make money from this or start a business. Just to build my portfolio

Comment: Ya... I think this question is gonna get voted down as too general, etc.  The answer is "it is hard and there is no one answer".  Maybe something like: figure out which library functions you are need to call, define a Server API for those functions and call them with some kind of REST/JSON over HTTP.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking along that too. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Moving the NLP functionality to a server will make the app useless for offline use which might be a drawback in the eyes of many users. If you nevertheless decide to go this route, I recommend a tutorial called [Converting a Functional API to REST](http://pettergraff.blogspot.co.at/2015/10/rest-api-part-ii-converting-functional.html) which describes the process of wrapping the API of a Java class (in your case an OpenNLP type such as [`POSTagger`](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/)) within a REST API.

Another option would be training your own models (see for instance the [Sentence Detector Training](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.training) section in the OpenNLP documentation). You could then reduce the size of the training sets such that the resulting models fit into your apk.

Obviously I wouldn't suggest compiling your own training data because this would take a lot of effort. Maybe you can find the training data used for the [offical OpenNLP models](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) and then simply reduce the size of the training sets. Asking a question to one of the [OpenNLP mailing lists](https://opennlp.apache.org/mail-lists.html) might be a good starting point for finding the official training data.

Another alternative might be to modify the official OpenNLP models by loading them into a Java program and somehow deleting data from them. I don't recommend going this route unless you understand the algorithms and data structures underlying the OpenNLP tools and therefore can judge whether this is at all possible.